# How can I show that $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}\cong A_{\mathfrak{p}_x}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

> Let $X$ be a scheme and $x\in X$. Let $V=\operatorname{Spec}(A)\subset X$ be an affine open in $X$ such that $x\in V$, I want to show that $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}\cong A_{\mathfrak{p}_x}$ where $\mathfrak{p}_x$ is the prime ideal of $A$ corresponding to $x$.

I have problems in finding such an isomorphism. I know that by definition $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}=\{(f,U):U\subset X~~\text{open}, f\in \mathcal{O}_X(U)\}/\sim$ where $(f,U)\sim (g,W)$ iff there exists $x\in H\subset U\cap W$ such that $f|_H=g|_H$. Furthermore we know that $A_{\mathfrak{p}_x}=S^{-1}A$ where $S=A\setminus \mathfrak{p}_x$. But I really don't see where to start for this isomorphism. Could maybe someone help me further?

Comment: Well, the claim is true when $X$ is affine. So it's enough to show that $O_{X,x}\cong O_{V,x}$ whenever $V$ is a neighborhood of $x.$ Using your description of $O_{X,x}$ do you see how to do this?

Comment: @D.Brogan Why is the claim true when $X$ is affine? Wouldn't this also be a proof?

Comment: The explicit isomorphism in the affine case is $\phi: O_{X,x}\to A_{\mathfrak p_x}$ given by $\phi([(f,U)])=f/1.$ Here $U=D(g)$ is a basic open and $f/1$ refers to the image of $f$ under the map $A_g\to A_{\mathfrak p_x}.$ You should prove that this is actually an isomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to prove can be stated as $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}\simeq\mathcal{O}_{V,x}$. We have a natural map $\mathcal{O}_{V,x}\longrightarrow\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$, it is injective because if $s_x\in\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ vanishes in a neighborhood of $x$ in $X$, say on an open $U$ of $X$, then it also vanishes on $U\cap V$ which is open in $V$. It is clearly surjective because a map defined in a neighborhood of $x$ in $X$ is also defined in a neighborhood of $x$ in $V$ by restriction.

Comment: your $s_x=[(f,U)]$ or what should $s_x$ be?

Comment: It would be $[(0,U)]$ here since it is supposed to vanish on a neighborhood of $x$ in $X$ that I called $U$.

Comment: and it only vanishes on $U\cap V$ since it need to have the same value on the whole $U$ and hence also on $U\cap V$?

Comment: Informally speaking, if you have a map defined on an open neighborhood of $x$ in $V$ that vanishes in an open neighborhood of $x$ in $X$, then it also vanishes on an open neighborhood of $x$ in $V$ by taking the intersection with $V$.

Comment: ah okey I see, but why does this isomorphism help me to prove my claim?

Comment: Since $V={\rm  Spec}(A)$ is an affine scheme, then $\mathcal{O}_{V,x}=A_{\mathfrak{p}_x}$.

Comment: Sorry I still don't see why this is an obvious equality $\mathcal{O}_{V,x}=A_{\mathfrak{p}_x}$

Comment: This the definition of an affine scheme !

Comment: But my definition of an affine scheme is that $O_X(D(f))=A_f$

Comment: Yes, and it implies that $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}=A_{\mathfrak{p}_x}$. If you were asked to do this exercise then you must have seen this.

Comment: Hmm I we have not seen this yet, I took a look at all my notes. So my question can I take $f=\mathfrak{p}_x$ then $$\mathcal{O}_X(D(f))=\mathcal{O}_X(D(\mathfrak{p}_x))=\mathcal{O}_X(\operatorname{Spec}(A_{\mathfrak{p}_x}))$$ But i only know that $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}(A)}(\operatorname{Spec}(A))=A$ but here we don't have in the "index" the same spectrum as in the "input"

Comment: No you can't, $f$ must be an element of $A$. It is proved in the Hartshorne, Proposition 2.2.(c) p.71 (freely available at http://userpage.fu-berlin.de/aconstant/Alg2/Bib/Hartshorne.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

**Question:**

> Let $X$ be a scheme and $x\in X$. Let $V=\operatorname{Spec}(A)\subset X$ be an affine open in $X$ such that $x\in V$, I want to show that $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}\cong A_{\mathfrak{p}_x}$ where $\mathfrak{p}_x$ is the prime ideal of $A$ corresponding to $x$.

**Answer:** There is an isomorphism

$$\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \cong (\mathcal{O}_X)_{V,x}$$

where $(\mathcal{O}_X)_V$ is the restriction of $\mathcal{O}_X$ to $V:=Spec(A)$. Hence the claim follows from the isomorphism

$$\mathcal{O}_{V,x}\cong A_{\mathfrak{p}_x}$$

where $\mathfrak{p}_x \subseteq A$ is the corresponding prime ideal in $A$.
When calculating the stalk of a sheaf $E$ at a point $x\in X$ this can be done using an arbitrary open subset $x\in V \subseteq X$.

You find details here:

[Why are these two stalks of sheaves equal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4612240/why-are-these-two-stalks-of-sheaves-equal)

**Comment:** "Why do we have $O_{V,x}=A_{p_x}$ if $V=Spec(A)$"

**Answer:** You find this result proved in the litterature (Hartshorne
Thm.I.3.2 for varieties and Prop.II.2.2 for schemes)

Comment: Why do we have $\mathcal{O}_{V,x}=A_{\mathfrak{p}_x}$ if $V=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$